# Accessing files from directory

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 directories specified below

```
\src - contains my .py file
\data - contains data to be accessed by .py file.
```

Irrespective of the system where the .py is executing I want it to pick up the files from \data.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what kind of files you wish to access(the file type that is) but if you want the path not to change regardless of location of main py file,

open terminal in **\data** and get working directory with:

`pwd`

That's the path to file you will use: i.e /opt/stuff/file.json

Comment: I want to use a .jpg file. Here if I use the .py file from some random pc,  the program should be able to access the .jpg.

Comment: Okay the above should work, if you are running the py in a different pc connecting using sockets it will hold. Try it then let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from your problem, you could mention the root folder and then traverse the directory structure.
The os.walk() is the way to it. You can find the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

But you would have to traverse the entire directory tree till you find your '/data'.

You have to join the current directory and the name to get the absolute path to a file

```
os.path.join(root, name)
```

Sample snippet:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/var/log"):
    print root
    print dirs
    print files
```

Comment: once this is specified, I dont have to go back and change my paths, though if am running my script from some random system right ?

Comment: Ideally YES !. Root path needs to be mentioned and as long as '/data' exists you can traverse down and find it. But not sure whether its an efficient solution because based on the hierarchy tree the search depth increase. But it should work.   Hope it helps